# only default session timeout works in C# aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am trying session timeout in my C# aspx.net application, but my session timeouts only by the default timeout set (i.e)20 minutes?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout='2'>

Comment: then, i hve changed timout in my IIS also...,i even tried with Global.asax

Comment: Is it IIS 7, right?

Comment: ya i have deployed in IIS 7 only

Comment: I post an answer but if it doesn't work for you, you have to share more details on your config

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in IIS 7+

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

With 20 meaning 20 minutes

Comment: did it work for u?? and do u have any idea to update my db with the session variable before my session expires?

Comment: Yes it works for me and no I have no idea of what you need beause I don't understand your question

Comment: THANK YOU Mathieu...i have my session say, session["user"], with timeout 20 minutes,within the time expires, i need my db to be updated with the value of session["user"]...so that a user with multiple logins will be restricted..